# Internet Explorer 11 support on windows 8.1

Tags: java, internet-explorer, applet

I've read that IE won't be supported on Windows 10 anymore.
Official page: [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/faq/internet-explorer-microsoft-edge#what-is-the-lifecycle-policy-for-internet-explorer-)

We have a Java applet application what we can run in Edge, but for certain types of Operating Systems (Windows 8.1), there is only Internet Explorer installed on the machines.

What is not clear for me that will Win 8.1 still have support for IE 11?

According to the documents yes, but I want to know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer 11 desktop application will still be supported on the following OS:

- Windows 8.1
- Windows 7 Extended Security Updates (ESU)
- Windows Server SAC (all versions)
- Windows 10 IoT Long-Term Servicing Channel (LTSC) (all versions)
- Windows Server LTSC (all versions)
- Windows 10 client LTSC (all versions)

So yes, Win 8.1 still have support for IE 11. For more information about IE 11 retirement, you can refer to [this doc](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/internet-explorer-11-desktop-app-retirement-faq/ba-p/2366549#h_40654177611649973578565).

Comment: Hi @GáborCsikós May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you might consider using CheerpJ Applet Runner, available for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cheerpj-applet-runner/bbmolahhldcbngedljfadjlognfaaein) and [Edge](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/cheerpj-applet-runner/ebfcpaoldmijengghefpohddmfpndmic)

It is an easy to use, single click extension that can run legacy Java applets in modern browsers securely and without requiring any additional software.

Full disclosure, I am CTO of Leaning Technologies and lead developer of the CheerpJ technology.

Please note that the CheerpJ Applet Runner extension is free *only* for private/personal use. Any other use requires a license. For more info see [here](https://leaningtech.com/cheerpj-applet-runner/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but my question was different:
Will Windows 8.1 still have support for IE 11?